# Duplicate class definition error

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts

Can anyone help resolve this?

```
15:02:06,698 ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "org/apache/jsp/tag/web/divBox_tag"
```

[geronimo 2.1, struts 1.2 ]

Comment: Need a little more information about your environment. What is your web application server and framework? This is normally caused by non-thread safe class loading in your context.

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance", don't do it next time

Comment: @hello_there_andy It's called being polite.

Comment: Apologies, I was trawling through salutation-removals and forgot to explain... the StackOverflow (simply, SO) community has policies that are democratically driven. 

Salutations go against policy, for more information: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts#

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try cleaning the deploy directory of whatever server you're using.

Try cleaning your project/s in the IDE you're using (try F5 the project/s, restart the IDE).

Try cleaning the project/s with the build tool you're using.