# Easymock3 Spring4.0.0.RELEASE cglib compatibility

Tags: java, spring-aop, easymock, cglib

I followed the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436600/unit-testing-spring-around-aop-methods) to try some unit tests with spring aop enabled methods. However, I suspect that the repackaged cglib classes under spring-core and the cglib-nodep-2.2.jar conflict with each other, causing my class being proxied to be loaded by the classloader twice. This results in the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name:
```

**Tools:**

1. easmock-3.0 (with cglib-nodep-2.2.jar transitive dependency)
2. spring-x-4.0.0.RELEASE (with repackaged cglib of version ? classes)
3. junit-4.8.1

Excluding the transitive cglib-nodep dependency didn't help obviously - all tests including non-sring-aop ones started failing too.

I tried the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7177186/934307) too: cleaning up the target folder before running the tests again with no success.

Is this problem really because of the conflict of cglib versions like I thought it would be? If so, what is the right version I should use that would stop loading my class twice.

Comment: Check for the what all dependancies are being used. Check WEB-INF/lib folder or using Dependancy hierarchy view in eclipse pom editor to know the duplicate jars, remove the older version.

Comment: I did, there was no duplicates in the cglib family. The spring people have repackaged the cglib classes into their spring-core, meaning cglib is not a transitive dependency that'll show up in the pom dependency view for us to spot the duplicate versions.

Comment: you can checkout the following link: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10242

Comment: That's exactly what I referred to, to conclude this could be a cglib version conflict! Like the post: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10242?focusedCommentId=87833&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-87833 says, they want us to use the cglib-3.0 repackaged classes instead of any other cglib lib with spring-3.2. However in my case, cglib-nodep that comes with easymock contains more than just what's available with spring for it to work. That's the problem.

Comment: Spiring 4 uses a repackaged version of cglib 3 as far as I know. It might be an ASM conflict down the drain. Have you tried upgrading cglib?

Comment: I did. I tried with both cglib 3 and cglib 3.1 with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: you do realise the age of this question?